# data inserted in email filed is not broadcasted properly to backend, request.is_ajax() returns false

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax, forms

I am following a tutorial about an ecommerce app.

The app is made with Django 4, and ajax is used in the frontend.

I am currently working on a contact page.

compiling the form and submiting should trigger a jquery-confirm popup displaying message "thank you a lot!".

This is obtained not by simple javascript submit form button
, but via a custom ajax logic.

The problem is that, when I compile and submit the form, the form is validated, the javascript is loaded, but the email data is not transmitted properly (I get None), and in views.py, `request.is_ajax()` returns None.

Note: 
In `mainapp_ecommerce/views.py` there is another function getting `request` as input which uses `request.is_ajax()`, and that one works fine.
Only the one linked with the form does not work properly.

This is what happens when I fill up all the form fields and click on submit:

backend:

```
contact_form.cleaned_data {'fullname': 'John Doe', 'email': None, 'content': 'uvyibuon'}
no ajax in this request: <WSGIRequest: POST '/contact/'>
[20/Nov/2023 16:21:15] "POST /contact/ HTTP/1.1" 200 16035
```

frontend:

```
Navigated to http://127.0.0.1:8000/contact/
contact/:255 readyyyy
contact/:261 before submit
```

Here are my files

### mainapp_ecommerce/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
...
path('contact/', contact_page, name="contact"),
]
```

### mainapp_ecommerce/views.py

```
from .forms import ContactForm

def contact_page(request):

    contact_form = ContactForm(request.POST or None)

    context = {
    "title":"Contact",
    "content":"Welcome to the contact page!",
    "form": contact_form,
    "brand":"new brand name",
    }

    if contact_form.is_valid():
        print("contact_form.cleaned_data", contact_form.cleaned_data)
        
        if request.is_ajax(): # asinchronous javascript and xml
            print("Ajax request")
        
            dict_for_jsonresponse = {
                "message": "thanks!!"
            }
            return JsonResponse(dict_for_jsonresponse)

        else:
            print("no ajax in this request:", request) 

    else:
         print("form not valid")    

    return render(request, "contact/view.html", context )
```

### mainapp_ecommerce/forms.py

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    # eredita dalla classe form di django

    fullname = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                "class": "form-control", 
                "placeholder":"Your full name", 
                "id":"form_full_name"
                }
        )
    )

    email = forms.EmailField(
        widget=forms.EmailInput(
            attrs={
                "class": "form-control", 
                "placeholder":"Your email", 
                }
        )
    )
    

    content = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.Textarea(
            attrs={
                "class": "form-control", 
                "placeholder":"Your content goes here...", 
                }
        )
    )

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get("email")
        if not "gmail.com" in email:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Email has to be gmail.com")
```

### mainapp_ecommerce/middlewares.py

```
class AjaxMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        def is_ajax(self):
            return request.META.get('HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH') == 'XMLHttpRequest'
        
        request.is_ajax = is_ajax.__get__(request)
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

### settings.py

```
...
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.AjaxMiddleware',
...
```

### templates/base.html

```
    {% load static %}
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        

        <!-- <title>Base template</title> -->
        {% include 'base/css.html' %} <!-- questo inietta il codice di una pagina nel punto in cui è messo -->

      </head>



      <body>

        {% include 'base/navbar.html' with brand_name='eCommerce' %}
        <div class='container'>
          {% block content %}
          {% endblock %}
        </div>


      {% include 'base/js.html' %}


        <script>
          $(document).ready(function(){

            console.log("readyyyy")
            // contact form habdrler
            var contactForm = $("contact-form")
            var contactFormMethod = contactForm.attr("method")
            var contactFormEndpoint = contactForm.attr("action")  /* questo lo prende da dove ho scritto action nella view dei contatti */
            
            console.log("before submit")

            contactForm.submit(function(event){
              console.log("entro submit")
              event.preventDefault()  /* quest mi serve a prevenire che lancio il submit premendo invio */
              var contactFormData = contactForm.serialize()
              console.log("serializzazione ok")
              var thisForm = $(this)
              
              $.ajax({

                method: contactFormMethod,
                url: contactFormEndpoint,
                data: contactFormData,

                success: function(data){
                  thisForm[0].reset()  /* empty the form */
                  $.alert({
                    title: "success!",
                    content: "thank you a lot!",
                    theme: "modern",
                  })              
                }, /* success chiudo */

                error: function(error){
                  console.log(error)
                  $.alert({
                    title: "oops",
                    content: "an error occurred",
                    theme: "modern",
                  })
                }, /* chiudo error */

              }) /* chiudo ajax  */


            }) /* chuso contactofrm submint */

        


          })
        </script>



        </body>
    </html>
```

### templates/contact/view.html

```
  {% extends "base.html" %}

  {% block content %}


  <!doctype html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <!-- Required meta tags -->
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

      <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

      <title>Contact</title>

    </head>

    <body>

      <div class='text-center'>
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
        <h3>we are working</h3>
      </div>



    <div class='container'>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='col'>      

        <div class='col-sm-6 col-12 mx-auto'>  <!-- mx auto lo manda nel mezzo -->

          <p>{{ content }}</p>

          <!-- <div class='col-sm-6 col-12'>
          <form method='POST'>
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder="Name" name='fullname'>
            <input type='email' class='form-control' placeholder="Email" name='email'>
            <input type='content' class='form-control' placeholder="Your content..." name='content'>
            <button type='submit' class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
          </form> -->

          <form class='contact-form' method='POST' action='{% url "contact" %}'>  
            <!-- questo token url mi serve per usare jquery,per essere sicuri che lo mando nel posto giusto. l'url lo prendo dalle views -->
            <!--  il selector della classe lo uso x jquery -->
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <br>
            <button type='submit' class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
          </form>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
    </div>

    <br><br>


      <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
      <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
  </html>


  {% endblock %}
```

Comment: `.is_ajax()` is even removed in Django 4 if I recall correctly, one of the reasons is that it is quite unreliable, and also does not make much sense.

Comment: Are you sure your SETTINGS is correct?  Shouldn't it be something like     `main_app_ecommerce.middlewares.AjaxMiddleWare`?

Comment: @SamSparx In `mainapp_ecommerce/views.py` there is another function getting `request` as input which uses `request.is_ajax()`, and that one works fine.
Only the one linked with the form does not work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your javascript refers to

```
var contactForm = $("contact-form")
```

However, this is actually looking for a tag of that type. It isn't correctly identifying the following:

```
<form class='contact-form' method='POST' action='{% url "contact" %}'>
```

To do so you need to modify the selector.  Assuming there is only one element of that class on the page, the following would do it (by adding the class indicator to the selector)

```
var contactForm = $(".contact-form")
```

But ideally you'd give the form either a name

```
<form class='contact-form' name="contact-form" method='POST' action='{% url "contact" %}'> 
var contactForm = $("form[name='contact-form']")
```

Or a unique ID

```
<form class='contact-form' id="contact-form" method='POST' action='{% url "contact" %}'>
var contactForm = $("#contact-form")
```